# SQL Server datetime filter query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    [Order Date], SUM([Profit]) 
FROM
    [sample].[dbo].[superstore]
WHERE  
    [Order Date] BETWEEN '2012-06-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2012-09-21 23:59:59.999'
GROUP BY 
    [Order Date]
ORDER BY  
    [Order Date];
```

result of this query has record with [Order Date] of `2012-06-21 00:00:00.000`

but with this query

```
SELECT 
    [Order Date], SUM([Profit]) 
FROM
    [sample].[dbo].[superstore]
WHERE  
    [Order Date] BETWEEN '2012-06-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2012-09-21 23:59:59.998'
GROUP BY 
    [Order Date]
ORDER BY 
    [Order Date];
```

I don't get this record.

Does SQL Server have any properties that is missing here?

Hint: type of `[Order Date]` is `datetime`.

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server has an accuracy of 3.33ms which leads to these odd rounding effects. It is recommended to use `DATETIME2(n)`, `DATE` and `TIME` instead, which were introduced in SQL Server 2008 - those types do not have this odd accuracy and rounding problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server date/time columns have precisions that vary depending on the exact type.  In your first, the "0.999" is being rounded up.

The safest approach is to eschew `between` and the time components, with something like:

```
SELECT [Order Date] , sum([Profit]) 
FROM [sample].[dbo].[superstore]
WHERE [Order Date] >=  '2012-06-21' AND
      [Order Date] < '2012-09-22'
GROUP BY [Order Date]
ORDER BY [Order Date];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the BETWEEN operator for date ranges seems appealing at first but, as you're finding out, it's a headache. If you stick to the following format, you'll find that it works no matter the date/time data type.

Note: Where BETWEEN is a logical >= and <=, we're shifting the "end date, to midnight of the following day.

```
SELECT
    [Order Date], SUM(Profit)
FROM
    sample.dbo.superstore
WHERE
    [Order Date] >= '2012-06-21'
    AND [Order Date] < '2012-09-22'
GROUP BY
    [Order Date]
ORDER BY
    [Order Date];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Query

```
 SELECT
  CAST([Order Date] AS date),
  SUM([Profit])
FROM [sample].[dbo].[superstore]
WHERE CAST([Order Date] AS date) BETWEEN '2012-06-21' AND '2012-09-21'
GROUP BY CAST([Order Date] AS date)
ORDER BY CAST([Order Date] AS date);
```